# how to prevent static method warning for class without attributes

Tags: python, oop, python-3.10

My task is to create a method for the class without any information about attributes and initializer, the method either raises an exception or returns an integer. For this method, I don't have to use any attributes or have `self` in code, and I can't make a function outside of the class instead.

Problem is that I get a warning from PyCharm that the method may be static, I suppose because neither attributes of class nor self were used, how can I change the method such that it satisfies my task and gets rid of the static warning?

```
class Analysis:
    name: str
    thesis: str
    id: int
    conclusions: List[Conclusion]
    

    def __init__(self, name_: str, thesis: str, id: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.thesis = thesis
        self.id = id
        self.conclusion = []

    def check_conclusion_criteria(self, conclusion: Union[int,str, bool]) -> bool:
    # Method body omitted.
    
    def assess_list_of_conclusions(self, lst: List[Conclusion]) -> int:
    # Method body omitted

class Conclusion:
    information: str, int, bool
    
    def __init__(self, information: Union[str, int, bool]) -> None
        self.information = information


class WrongConclusionError(exception):
    """ Error which is raised when conclusion for analysis is wrong. """

class GradingScheme:
    
     def grade_analysis(self, conclusions: List[Conclusion], analysis: Analysis) -> int:
         """Return grade between 0 and 100, showing how well this analysis was performed. 
         Raise WrongConclusionError if any conclusion in <conclusions> does not satisfy criteria. Return 101 if length of <conclusions> is 1."""
         if len(conclusions) == 1:
             return 101
         for conclusion in conclusions:
             if not analysis.check_conclusion_criteria(conclusion):
                 raise WrongConclusionError
         avg_grade = 0
         avg_grade = avg_grade + 
         analysis.assess_list_of_conclusions(conclusions)
         return avg_grade // len(conclusions)
```

Comment: "Problem is that method becomes static as not attributes and self was not used" - no, that's not how static methods work. Static methods are created with `@staticmethod`. Just not using instance information doesn't make a method static.

Comment: You might be getting an IDE warning telling you you safely *could make* the method static, since it doesn't need `self`, but that's just telling you something *you could do* if you wanted.

Comment: please, indent Python code correctly in your question. This is not really valid Python.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I should have specified that. IDE warns me that method may be static. I am looking for a way to get rid of this warning.